# HyperV: Best way to sharing Host Partition with all Guest Machines?

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine, permissions, hyper-v, mapped-drive

I'm trying to set up a lab environment. I have a guest with 1 2TB harddrive 16gb ram running Server 2012R2.

My host partition is is split like this:

- C: 200GB
- HyperV (F): 600GB (this only contains VM files)
- HyperShare (S): 200GB (Trying to use as shared storage for all VMs)

I have HyperV role enabled on the host and 4 VMs (DC1, SQL1 AND 2 AND SP1).

What I did was shared HyperShare with "Everyone" gave full permission and in Security I gave "Everyone" Full Control.

In the DC at created a GPO at user level to map to Network Drive and assigned it to HyperShare.

When I login under a domain user I see the mapped drive but if I run powershell scripts stored in that drive I get permission errors. All I want to do is be able to easily share this partition between all my VMs with full permissions

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have added the HyperShare disk as secondary disk in hyperv manager. In stead you should make a share on your host partition and access this share in all your guests.

This is of course granted that it only is a lab env. you are setting up.